# Relationship between these Linux based OS

Tags: linux

Guys can you site the relationship between these List of OS:

```
1.RedHat
2.Fedora and
3.CentOS
```

Thanks

Comment: Please explain what you mean by "relationship", and what your research has already told you. What actual problem are you facing, and why'd you need to know?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. RedHat - actually RHEL -RedHat Enterprise Linux. Upstream. To get updates you have to pay. You get as well support.
2. Fedora - community supported, cutting edge Linux. RedHat supports this project. It is intended for home users and not for production. RedHat is based on Fedora (so some things from Fedora will end up in RedHat)
3. CentOS - RHEL recompiled with all RH logos repleaced. Free 100% binary compatible with RHEL Linux. Community support. Can be run in production but they are usually late 1-2 days with patches (have to wait for Upstream Vendor to release them and then recompile, Q&A etc).